# How to perform one hot encoding in Spark on a string column that has comma separated values?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
val df = Seq(
(1,"a,b,c"),
(2,"b,c")
).toDF("id","page_path")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

df.show()


+---+---------+
| id|page_path|
+---+---------+
|  1|    a,b,c|
|  2|      b,c|
+---+---------+
```

I want to perform one hot encoding on this page_path column such that the output would look like -

[image: output]

Can I do this using one-hot encoding in Spark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column "page_path" can be split, and then values exploded, and pivoted:

```
 df
  .withColumn("splitted", split($"page_path",","))
  .withColumn("exploded", explode($"splitted"))
  .groupBy("id")
  .pivot("exploded")
  .count()
  // replace nulls with 0
  .na.fill(0)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|id |a  |b  |c  |
+---+---+---+---+
|1  |1  |1  |1  |
|2  |0  |1  |1  |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Guess, aggregate function have to be used in Pivot, like here:
https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/01/sql-pivot-converting-rows-to-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Solution {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("SparkClusterApp")
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(sparkConf).getOrCreate

    import sparkSession.implicits._

    val df = Seq((1, "a,b,c"),(2, "b,c")).toDF("id", "page_path")
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
    df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"page_path", "\\,")).select( $"id",
      when(array_contains($"_tmp","a"),"1").otherwise("0").as("is_a"),
      when(array_contains($"_tmp","b"),"1").otherwise("0").as("is_b"),
      when(array_contains($"_tmp","c"),"1").otherwise("0").as("is_c")).show()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in the question you mentioned `df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")` thought of giving sql version of the same thing which pasha done.

[***In Databricks documenation they have mentioned many use cases with Pivot***...](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/01/sql-pivot-converting-rows-to-columns.html)
Below is the sql version for sql lovers.

In this approach, contrary to dataframe operations approach `pivot` uses implicit grouping there is no need for seperate `group by` clause in the sql.

```
 val df: DataFrame = Seq((1, "a,b,c"),(2, "b,c")).toDF("id", "page_path")
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
  spark.sql(
    """
      |Select * from
      |( select id, explode(split( page_path ,',')) as exploded from df )
      |pivot(count(exploded) for exploded in ('is_a','is_b','is_c')
      |)
    """.stripMargin).na.fill(0).show
```

Result :

```
+---+----+----+----+
| id|is_a|is_b|is_c|
+---+----+----+----+
|  1|   0|   0|   0|
|  2|   0|   0|   0|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: @Regressor check sql version of the answer